# filtrar rotas por uma prop no meta. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

tenho uma prop no meta de algumas rotas chamada "displayName", queria jogar todas as rotas que tivessem essa prop numa navbar.. Já tentei mas sem sucesso, até o momento consigo puxar todas as rotas para o componente nav, e usando o v-for eu monto os links na navbar, mas dessa forma aparecem todas as minhas rotas, e eu quero apenas algumas especificas... segue um exemplo de rota com essa prop e e o que eu fiz até o momento:

Rota:

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home, name: 'Home', 
    meta: {
       displayName: 'Home' 
    }
  } 
];
```

Função que pega as rotas no componente nav:

```
computed: {
  routes(){
    return this.$router.options.routes
  }
},
```

E o v-for que cria os links dentro da nav:

```
<router-link v-for="(r, index) in routes" :key="index" class="links" :to="r">{{ r.name }}</router-link>
```

A ideia é ter apenas links de rotas com a prop displayName, e usar o valor dessa prop no display do link.

Obrigado pela atenção desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de iterar sobre as rotas, execute um [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) na array de rotas. Assim você consegue ter um array apenas com as rotas que deseja. Na `computed`, faça:

```
computed: {
    routes() {
      return this.$router.options.routes.filter(route => "meta" in route && "displayName" in route.meta)
    }
}
```

O operador `in` verifica se uma propriedade pertence a determinado objeto. Na primeira comparação, verificamos se o objeto `meta` existe na rota analisada, visto que essa não é uma propriedade obrigatória de uma rota no Vue. Posteriormente, caso o objeto `meta` exista, verificamos se este possui propriedade `displayName`.

Já para criar o menu, basta iterar sobre esse novo array:

```
<router-link v-for="(route, index) in routes" :key="index" class="links" :to="route.path">{{ route.meta.displayName }}</router-link>
```

Comment: funcionou mt bem, obrigado.